# how to log dmidecode results using bash

Tags: bash, logging

I have been trying to write a bash script to log dmidecode results in the a log file.

Till now, this is how far I got.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 0 5`; do
sudo su <<HERE
dmidecode -t $i >> system.log 
HERE

done
```

When I execute the above script, it asks for my password. As soon as I enter the password, I get the following error 6 times.

```
bash: line 1: system.log: Permission denied
```

Anybody has any idea on how to solve this and log the dmidecode details. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Results of `ls -l` ?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Redirections aren't expanded inside here-docs, so I suspect that the problem lies elsewhere; the OP's script, as far as I can tell, _should_ work.

Comment: @mklement0 Ok, good. I was too lazy to test that to find out. Which probably means the issue is just an "ordinary" permissions issue on that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command as written *should* work, but it can be simplified:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..5}; do
  sudo -s <<<"dmidecode -t $i >> system.log"
done
```

If the above doesn't work, let us know.

- `sudo -s` takes a *shell* command to execute as root from stdin<sup>[1]</sup>, so there's no need for `su`; since the command is simple enough, I'm using a here-*string* (`<<<`) instead of a here-document.

  - **Note how the output redirection, `>> system log`, is *part of the command string***, as it would otherwise happen in the context of the *current* user:

    - `sudo -s <<<"dmidecode -t $i" >> system.log` *would* actually produce the error you describe, if you executed it in a directory in which the current user is not allowed to create files.
  - The upshot is that the resulting `system.log` file will be owned by `root`.
- `{0..5}` uses a brace expansion to drive the iteration, which is more efficient.

---

<sup>[1] `sudo -s` *also* accepts a command as additional *arguments*, but such a command passed this way is limited to *simple* commands *without redirections*, so it wouldn't work in this case.

Additionally, you cannot pass such a command as a *single* string, which requires passing - and quoting - its arguments individually.

*Older* versions of `sudo` - such as found on macOS up to 10.11 - *did* allow passing an entire shell command line as a *single* argument, but that should no longer be used - use stdin input.</sup>